# Tensorflow LSTM RNN output activation function

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I have an input image with grey scale values ranging from let's say `25000 - 35000`. I'm doing a binary pixel-wise classification, so the output ground truth is a matrix of either `0's` or `1's`.

Does anyone know what the default output activation function is? My question is, is it a ReLu? I want it to be a SoftMax function. In which case, each prediction value would be between `0` and `1` (obviously close to my ground truth data).

I'm using example code from [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py) that I have adjusted to make work for my data.

I have a working network that is training, but the minibatch loss is at about 425 right now and the accuracy at 0.0, and for the LSTM MNIST example code (linked) the minibatch loss was about 0.1 and the accruacy about 1.0. My hope is that if I can change the activation function to use the SoftMax function, I can improve results.

Comment: AFAIK there is no default. You have to specify the activation functions. The example you linked just returns the result of the matmul, which is akin to linear activation.

Comment: @drxzcl is there a way I can take the output of the matmul and pass it through a softmax?

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b2a812b962f8088a8256d4e6271b9cd425936446/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L351), the default activation function for `BasicLSTMCell` is `tf.tanh()`. You can customize the activation function by specifying the optional `activation` argument when constructing the `BasicLSTMCell` object, and passing any TensorFlow op that expects a single input and produces a single output of the same shape. For example:

```
# Defaults to using `tf.tanh()`.
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

# Uses  `tf.relu()`.
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, activation=tf.nn.relu)

# Uses  `tf.softmax()`.
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

Comment: my question with this method is... is this the activation function for each cell? or is it the activation function for the output layer? from the research I have done, `tanh()` is what works best for LSTM cells, so I'm looking for an activation function from the output layer (the final layer)

Comment: also, `module object has no attribute softmax`

Comment: same for relu function

Comment: I fixed the typos - thanks for pointing them out. And yes, the activation functions here are for the individual cells. The output layer is specified outside the RNN/LSTM code, and in fact it uses an [explicitly created softmax](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/bf72a97258e201a95886d17d8d7cf07d265102fb/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py#L76) as part of the cross entropy cost function.

Comment: Wow, you are right. Thanks for the correction.I removed my answer.